# How to save a nested array in function to another.py script?

Tags: python, arrays, string-formatting, f-string

I would like to save an array (please see example bellow) to another file with using write-core function

HERE_MY_ARRAY = [0.01,0.02,0.4]

attribute - for example: reject_request, open_session etc.

```
  f = open("methods.py", "w")
  f.write('''\
def %s(self):
        \tyield self.env.timeout(random.choice(HERE_MY_ARRAY))
    ''' % (str('open_session')))
    f.close()
```

At the I would like to get sth like that:

```
def open_session(self):
        yield self.env.timeout(random.choice([0.01,0.02,0.4]))
```

Comment: JSON?  Pickle?  Eval?

Comment: You've already used `%s`, just use `%r` instead of `HERE_MY_ARRAY`.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I used the pickle to collect data and transfer to another .py file properly.